Would Europeans be effective slaves on Caribbean Plantations?
I've came across several stories of a type of "role reversal" where Europeans wind up enslaved by either Africans or Native Americans.
I'm writing a timeline where Europe undergoes a very different history and Africa is more advanced. A Roman Empire analogue ends up exporting convicts, slaves, and paupers from Europe, North Africa, and Atlantis to the Americas. Would this be sustainable? Or would Europeans keep dying off due to malaria or skin cancer or rough conditions or another factor?
I remember reading one reason indentured servitude ended early in the Americas was due to Europeans keep getting sick and dying in tropical conditions. The same thing happened in early African colonies.

Indentured servitude declined far more due to the cheaper cost of slavey than ever illness. If you could live through it, it was actually a pretty good deal. And the tropics were only Florida and the Carolinas. Frankly, we focus on black slavery in the U.S. so much that we often forget that everbody of every color has been trafficked as slaves. In fact, european slavery was such a big thing that your question here might be moot.

we could use some clarifications about when and where this issue is taking place. Please consider the convesation Tom Bebop and I had in comments to his answer. Thanks.

Question: which europeans, exactly. There are many different genetic groups - the Celts (Red heads, no souls) the Scandinavians (Tall), Icelandic (Really tall, Really strong), Dutch (Lanky) etc. etc. I feel this would have a significant impact on the answer.

??? It's not that Europeans died like flies, it's that European countries had armies and it was not easy to go hunting for slaves. England and France did export "onvicts, slaves, and paupers from Europe" to the Americas (and Australia etc.) in real history. England did it on a relatively large scale, with maybe about 100,000 total involuntary indentured servants exported to the Americas, mostly convicts and Irish and Scottish prisoners of war. (A famous example is of course Captain Blood.)

@TheDemonLord I'm sorely tempted to ask where you hail from because I about died laughing when I read, the Celts (Red heads, no souls). Not that I'm looking forward to meeting one in a dark alley. I'm pretty sure I'd lose that fight and get teabagged for my trouble.

I'm British originally, live in NZ

Any superficial research (including asking for bite sized answers on Stack Exchange) into the history of emotionally loaded things such as racial traits, the relative power of different geographical-racial regions, and slavery is absolutely 100% guaranteed to make a person more wrong about history, not more right. If you want to write a radical alt-history that isn't stupid, you must become an expert with an expert's depth of knowledge... and then you must convey that depth of knowledge to your readers, who are almost certain to come in to your story stupid and wrong about everything.

@AlexP Europeans bought Africans slaves from other Africans, in exchange for manufactured goods.

given how many slaves died of smallpox and other european deseases plus malnutrition and the sicknesses from being crammed inot a boat like cordwood, high death rates was not a factor slavers seem to care about.

The basic problem during the 1800's was malaria which had been introduced to the Americas. While mosquitoes are common north of the Mason Dixon line, the malaria Plasmodium inside them would not. [1] People from Africa who had the genes to make them tolerant of the disease would survive. (Unfortunately, if you got that gene from both parents, you would get sickle cell anemia.) (There are other blood diseases that provide immunity to malaria. [2] Europeans and Native Americans were very susceptible to the disease and up to 50% of Europeans brought to the South would die the first year.
Europeans have been used as slaves from the earliest recorded times. Vikings often traded slaves. [3]
Slavery is not as productive as other economic systems as slaves are not as motivated to work.

Malaria is not native to America. It was brought to America by African slaves.  If you instead had a European based slave population,  you would have seen similar epidemics of European diseases in the South like smallpox which Africans are 50% less resistant too than Europeans.

Physically there's not enough difference between any "nation" or "race" to be worthy of discussion. The only substantial difference is the colour of the skin. The notion that Sub-Saharan Africans are tougher and more brawny, and Europeans are weaker and more suited to intellectual tasks is just another stereotype.
European slaves would suffer from sunburn, and there would be deaths from cancer, but the life expectancy among slaves is short anyway. Mud is a practical way of protecting one's skin, as are clothes and hats. Skin does tan and protect itself with time. Malaria is a killer of Africans as well as Europeans. Sickle cell immunity is only about 10% of Black Africans.
Culturally you would have to imagine that the technologies that allowed the slave trade were developed in Africa, but this is easily handwaved.  There's nothing intrinsic about the people of Europe and Africa that makes one slavers, and the other slaves.

Precisely, no slave owner is going to care about sunburn.

Well, Africans had 200 000-400 000 years headstart compared to Europeans (or actually Africans migrating to Europe, whom, in the process, also committed the first documented genocide (of the native Europeans - the Neanderthals)) but never achieved more than stone age technology. The Europeans (and Middle Easterners, Indians, Chinese etc) started at the stone age level but in a few tens of thousands of years advanced passed that. So yes, SOME difference does exist.

Not really.  Firstly on the genocide, https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/articles/cwydgyy8120o next it's not like there was a "headstart".  African people didn't arrive from outer space, and then 200,000 years later, European people followed from outer space.  The people migrating into Europe brought with them such technology that had been already been developed. It's just that until recently in our past, we were too busy surviving to move beyond basic Acheulean tools.

@d-b as in environmental differences you mean? I have heard theories that cold climates (especially seasonally cold climates) do provoke technological progress to deal with the winter food scarcity and other winter hazards

@JamesK The BBC-article doesn't contradict that Homo Sapiens killed off the Neanderthals. Re African tech: nothing happened for several hundred thousands years with it. It was the same stone age tech the whole period. Meanwhile, in 50 000 years African migrants developed from stone age to what we have today. Imagine if that process had started 400 000 years ago. Where will we be in 350 000 years from now? It is completely unimaginable what tech will have then (if we survive).

@RichardTingle Cognitive (dis)abilities are 80-90 % inheritable so I think it has much more to do with that than environmental factors. Proof in case: there has been ancient civilizations in quite different environment outside Africa. As soon as the population becomes dense/big enough, the development starts. Look at Northern Europe.

"European slaves would suffer from sunburn".  LOL, Europeans would wear clothes.  Short sleeve shirts are a relatively new development.  Wide-brimmed hats existed too, as did neck flaps.

The sunburn thing is a non-issue.  Keep in mind that even at the height of slavery, only about 30% of the south was black.  The other 70% did not just hide inside all day, most were farmers, ranchers, and other forms of outdoor laborers.  White people can tan and choose favorable clothing to adapt to sunny climates just fine.

History

The history of the Caribbean bears out that many Europeans did in fact end up labouring on plantations in the region. By the late 17th century, somewhere between 10 and 50 per cent of the population of any given British island territory was Irish.

Imperial slavery, of the Roman type, was not the chattel slavery that we find in the Good Old Days of the USA. The kind of slavery your setting demands is a highly complex social infrastructure that would include war prisoners, debtors, slaves by birth, slaves by circumstance, perhaps even slaves by choice. This kind of slavery knew no ethnic, national, religious, or status boundaries. You might be a king today and a slave by next Thursday. Or, you might be a highly placed slave today and made a freeman by manumission. Slaves in this kind of system could be bog standard unskilled labourers, or they could be skilled craftsmen, civil servants, physicians, teachers, sex workers, accountants, etc.

The system would be sustainable so long as the conditions that allow for it to remain in existence actually remain in existence. If Christianity exists in your world, that would be ultimately the death knell of slavery of any kind. Even if it doesn't, other cultural and technological factors could serve to reduce the need for a large slave population.

The take away here is that disease in and of itself isn't the limiting factor. So long as your empire has a supply of fresh slaves, those who die from disease can be easily replaced. Ultimately, slaves will end up intermarrying and you'll end up with a population that is relatively immune to such diseases anyway, so the few imports who die off won't affect the total population too much.

"If Christianity exists in your world, that would be ultimately the death knell of slavery of any kind." - Why do you say this?

The American South and South America disproves the notion that Christianity would be the death knell of slavery. People adjusted their Christianity to support the economics. What killed slavery in the American North was not religion, but the economic superiority of empowering people to work for their own interest through small farms and small industries.

"Slaves, obey your earthly masters with respect[a] and trembling, in singleness of heart, as you obey Christ, 6 not with a slavery performed merely for looks, to please people, but as slaves of Christ, doing the will of God from the soul. 7 Render service with enthusiasm, as for the Lord and not for humans, 8 knowing that whatever good we do, we will receive the same again from the Lord, whether we are enslaved or free." - the New Testament has lots of praise for Slavery.  It was the Enlightenment that broke Slavery, not Christianity itself.

@JollyJoker -- Christianity universalises the concept that all men are created equal. There is neither Jew nor Greek; neither slave nor free. Christianity completely does away with worldly categories, makes them meaningless. When Christianity is applied to the world, evils like slavery fall away.

@DavidR -- Actually, all this shows is that people can turn an objective good into an evil.  We never would have had an American North, nor even an America, if it were not for Christianity. So many things depend on it!

@Yakk --- These are not said in praise of slavery. Slavery is undone by teachings such as divine sonship and inalienable & intrinsic worth of the human person.

@elemtilas I am aware that post-Enlightenment theology, informed by secular humanism, rewrites Christian theology to be anti-Slavery.  But the same textual sources was read as very much pro-Slavery for 1000+ years.  It is rather silly to state that Slavery couldn't survive Christianity, when it quite clearly can and did.  I won't continue to disagree with your personal religious faith, but it isn't very convincing.  Good fortune, and may your faith bring you comfort.

@Yakk Slavery significantly declined in the Late Roman Empire after it Christianized and was mostly gone from Europe until it was re-introduced by the Atlantic Trade Triangle.  Yes, some churches advocated for it in America, and tried to justify it with scripture, but those same Churches also read out that WHOLE passage which continues on to say "...And masters, treat your slaves in the same way. Do not threaten them, since you know that he who is both their Master and yours is in heaven, and there is no favoritism with him."

So, this same Bible passage that some used to justify it was also the exact source of the idea that all men (even slaves) are created equal.  Without it, this idea would have never made its way into the Enlightenment's way of thinking which eventually lead to a massive decline in slavery for the second time in Western Civilization: Both caused by Christianity.

Also, the resurgence of slavery that happened in America was caused by Muslim influences.  Muslims created the slave trade problem in Africa hundreds of years before Christians even considered it.  When Christians did start buying African slaves, they had no intention of mistreating them, but the Muslims taught Christian merchants how to manage slaves through cruelty and dehumanization and warned them that the slaves would turn on and kill them if they didn't.

@Nosajimiki Your version of history ignores how the Spanish tried to turn the Native Americans into slaves far earlier than they imported Africans.

@DavidR And you are ignoring how much Christianity curbed the Spanish enslavement of natives.  Christopher Columbus would have become the first conquistador, but when he told king Ferdinand II that  the Taíno people could be easily subjugated, his proposal was rejected for being unchristian, and the king outlawed the enslavement of native Americans.  Exceptions were later added into Spanish law based on moral justifications: they could buy slaves from Native tribes that already engaged in slavery because they believed a Christian slave owner would treat them better than a pagan slave owner

(which they typically did), they could enslave cannibals by force as this was seen as morally superior to killing or allowing them to live free, or they could force into labor those captured as a result of a "just war" which is still allowed to this day under the articles of the Geneva Convention and international law in general.  So, while there were a few slaves in Spanish America, the vast majority of the conquered natives were not slaves, they were encomienda: serfs who had basic property rights and protection under the law which were very similar to European peasants.

And like European peasants, they were required to pay a tax in either goods or labor in exchange for the protection of their lord.  So, while it is sometimes represented as slavery because encomienda could be compelled to work, this compelled work was only supposed to be enough to cover their tax obligation when they lacked other means to pay it.  And when it became apparent that this system was being abused and transitioning into a form of slavery,

it was friar Bartolomé de Las Casas that convinced Charles V to outright ban the enslavement of natives in the Spanish colonies in 1542 declaring that any Native born in Spanish territory from that point forward would have the full rights of Spanish citizenship.

Quote from Tacitus about germans.
"They are less able to bear laborious work. Heat and thirst they cannot in the least endure; to cold and hunger their climate and their soil inure them."
I vaguely recall mentions amongst historians of romans trying to stage battle in the height of summer and the middle of the day. So maybe not all europeans would be suitable.
link to quote source

This quote really needs context. It was the Gemanic tribes who finally sacked Rome, after all.

Good point, I would counter that the Mediterranean climate is more temperate than the tropics. Europeans can function in heat, i would just argue its not what they are best at.

I could wish Rhymehouse would clarify that issue about the topics. Only a handful of the original 13 colonies were "tropical" (and that, not really). Considered as a whole, the U.S. has almost no tropical land. Nothing north of the Carolinas is tropical nor west of the Mississippi River. That whole assertion doesn't make a lot of sense. Heck, it was the Europeans who brought disease to the Americas. Rhymehouse, we might all be thinking about the U.S. Are you considering Central and South America along with all this? That might make the Q too broad.

Sorry im Australian. I was under the impression that most the slaves were for harvesting Sugarcane, a tropical plant. Cotton and Tobaco as well, but arent they hot weather plants?

That's my concern. Sugarcane was Cental and South American. Cotton was mostly the southern U.S., and tobacco was grown in both locations. But by the time any of those three industries really got going, the U.S. was into its Civil War (mid 1800s) and the Banana Republics were forming. There was still slavery, but it was on its way out (later in South America than in North America). We're talking about a 200 year time span across the entire western hemisphere. That's  a lot of question.

@JBH the slaves aren't going to the USA. They're going to the Caribbean. Read the title.

@Rhymehouse -- The slaves are going " to the Americas". Read the question body. That's a lot of land, tropical and otherwise.

Frame Challenge #1: White People DID work as slaves on Caribbean Plantations
While this is a controversial topic, many modern historians are finding that there is a lot of confusion and misinformation about how many slaves were actually white because of the liberal use of the word "Negro".  When 20th century historians tried to determine how many slaves were of African decent, they concluded that all or nearly all slaves were black because they assumed that Negro literally meant black people.  However, it is now clear from a wide range of seemingly conflicting documents that "Negro" was more commonly used as a generic term for any sort of prisoner or slave.  For example, during the the American Revolution and the War of 1812, British POWs were called Negros even though we know from context that very few would have been black.  There are also many old letters, prison records, and plantation records describing Negros of various European nationalities and paintings clearly showing white slaves working alongside African slaves.
Based on this new understanding of how to read historical documents when determining racial demographics, many historians have been working to re-evaluate the actual demographics of the American slave trade.  One such historian, Thomas Bartlett, determined that in the 17th Century, as many as 12,000 slaves in Barbados alone were likely of European (mostly Irish) decent.  Since there is no record of productivity or survival rate for these European slaves being any different than their African counterparts, it suggests that the use of European slaves in the Caribbean worked just fine.
We also have plenty of records of white freemen working in every part of Colonial America as homesteaders doing the exact same kinds of work as the African slaves which further invalidates any claim that whites could not have been used to work the land.
Frame Challenge #2: You Need to Change European Values, not their wealth or relative tech level
Ultimately, the slavery issue of Europeans comes down to a matter of values.  In between the time of the late Roman Empire and the end of the Renaissance, slavery was much less practiced in Europe than the rest of the world, even though they were for a large portion of that time less advanced than many non-European civilizations. The total average slave population of Europe in the Medieval period was only ~10%, and most of the slave trade was isolated to the Pagan and Muslim parts of Europe.  Furthermore, there were many laws all across Europe that prohibited the enslavement of Christians, prevented the sale of Christians to non-Christians, and/or prevented various forms of slavery all together.
In contrast, most parts of Africa and the Middle East were 20-50% enslaved and freely sold slaves to foreigners.  The single biggest reason why Europeans turned to Africa for slaves was because the Africans were so willing to be complicit in the enslavement and sale of their own people.  There is a lot of work and risk involved in invading foreign lands to take slaves, but in Africa, there were simply so many people for sale that European traders could sail into a port, buy who they wanted, and leave with very little risk or wasted time.
In contrast, when various Viking and Muslim groups decided they want to make a habit out of raiding and enslaving the people of Europe, the Europeans by-in-large did not become complicite with slavery. Instead they became more defensive by building up fortifications, arming commoners to be able to defend themselves, and banding together into stronger coalitions unto the point that they became too dangerous and unprofitable to be worth raiding for slaves.
If an advanced African or Atlantis civilization wanted to create a major slave trade out of Europe, you'd have to significantly revise the culture of Europe to make collusion with foreign slave merchants a more agreeable practice.  Otherwise the invading slavers will simply choose a less resistive population to target for slavery.
The best way to do this would probably be to get rid of the Catholic Church.  Most of the laws that limited slavery and the political alliances that allowed Europe to resist outside domination came from decrees made by the Church.  If you instead allow Roman and/or Norris paganism to dominate the continent, then you'd have a population that is fundamentally less united and more agreeable to selling their own neighbors to outsiders.

There were penal colonies in Caraibbean - France for sure had theirs, others maybe as well. Those were places where convicted criminals were sent from Europe and back in the day those supplied what essentially was slave labor to local industries. So you need to look at survival ratio in such places and how many people actually finished the sentence.

If I remember correctly, the slave trade from Africa to America started because indigenous people didn't fare well with the harsh working conditions, while the African were more robust and strong.
If you think that in those times the Muslim regions already traded in European and North African slaves and employed many themselves, it would have been easier to trade with an already established market actor rather than starting from scratch, if the "merchandise" would have been up to spec.
So, no, I don't think European would have made good quality work force.

By "indigenous" you mean the Native Americans. They're not Europeans and though I'd need to prove it, I suspect it wasn't tat they were less robust or strong, but more wild and unruly. Considering it was the Europeans, not the Africans, who built the ships and willingly made the journey into the unknown... why would they make a poor workforce? (This isn't white supremacy talking, it's me wondering if you did reverse the innovative roles of the two continents, would the Europeans actually be poor workers? History doesn't really support that, does it?)

Ugh, in the relevant timeframe the northern shore of the Mediterranean just did not trade with the southern shore. Really, trade between Christian Europe and Muslin Northern Africa was less than minimal, as the two hated each other with a passion. And anyway, the number of available European slaves was very low; European countries tended to have armies and navies. (In previous times yes, very many Central and Eastern Europeans got sold into slavery to the Turks and Moors. But that lucrative Venetian and Genoese trade dried up long before Columbus opened the New World.)

It wasn't that the Native Americans were unsuited to the labor desired, it was that they knew the territory and the locals and could therefore escape more easily. Imported Africans didn't have those, and could more easily be kept from those when they started being "home grown", and so were more dependent on their slavers for basic survival

Don't overlook, of course, the fact that if all of your slaves fit a certain demographic, and very few — if any — of the non-slaves fit that demographic, then it is a lot harder for the slaves to escape and blend into the general population.  Enslaved Natives could just go back to local tribes.  White people could become indistinguishable from the slave owners.  But if the only black people around were those you'd brought to the continent explicitly as slaves, then the question upon seeing an 'unattended' black person was not "are they an escaped slave?", but just "whose slave are they?"

I definitely remember reading about native populations dying off under harsh (slave) working conditions and being replaced with imported African slaves.

@Jedediah It is true native americans died a lot, but it was not tropical diseases that kept killing them. It was European diseases.  Africa and Europe had a lot of the same communicable diseases so they shared similar herd immunities, but slavery forced natives into too much direct contact with their European counterparts and the small pox and similar illnesses that comes with that.

Short answer: no. Until fairly recently in history, the Caribbean tended to be a death trap for Europeans.
Brandon F. has a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pESTuHjmG6g&t) detailing why the West Indies was a complete hellhole for British (and other European) military units assigned there, and the issues that caused regiments to be utterly devastated without anyone firing a shot at them would be the same as those facing any European slaves.
